# TabbedPage with searchbar on xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I am working on a multiplatform (android/ios) xamarin forms app.

I do not want to write specific code for iOS or Android.

I am trying to put a search bar at the top my tabbed page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="XXXX.YYYY">


        <SearchBar Placeholder="" Text="">
        </SearchBar>

        <TabbedPage.Children>

            <ContentPage x:Name="content1" Title="P1">
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="label1"
                       Text="Test de page 1"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </ContentPage>

            <ContentPage x:Name="content2" Title="P2">
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="label2"
                       Text="Test de page 2"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </ContentPage>

        </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```

But i get an error, the search bar cannot be put there.
How should i do in order to have the searchbar on the top of the screen ?

Thanks

Comment: You could implement a `SearchBar` at the top of each `ContentPage`

Comment: This is what i done but there is no cleanest solution ?